# jQueryUI Dialog with Ajax Form Won't Close with $(this).dialog("close");

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQueryUI Dialog loading up a form from an external url, the form renders fine and posts ok but neither the save or cancel buttons seem to close the form yet the dialog close icon does it's job just fine.

Here is my script that spawns the dialog and should handle the buttons:

```
  $(function () {
      $('a.modal').on('click', function() {
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          $("#modalAdd").html("")
              .dialog({
                  title: $(this).attr("title"),
                  width: 400,
                  height: 300,
                  buttons: {
                      "Save": function() {
                          $.post(href,
                              $("form").serialize(),
                              function() {
                                  $(this).dialog("close");
                              });
                      },
                      Cancel: function() {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                      }
                  }
              })
              .load(href, function() {
                  $(this).dialog("open");
              });

          return false;
      });
  });
```

The final solution was to declare the variable outside of the scope of the dialog declaration as follows:

```
 $(function () {
      $('a.modal').on('click', function() {
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          var modal = $("#modalAdd");
          modal.html("")
              .dialog({
                  title: $(this).attr("title"),
                  width: 400,
                  height: 300,
                  buttons: {
                      "Save": function() {
                          $.post(href,
                              $("form").serialize(),
                              function() {
                                  modal.dialog("close");
                              });
                      },
                      Cancel: function() {
                          modal.dialog("close");
                      }
                  }
              })
              .load(href, function() {
                  **modal**.dialog("open");
              });

          return false;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried to find out if `$(this)` inside your `Save` function is what you think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is changed in the ajax callback function, you need to cache to a local variable.

```
"Save": function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.post(href, $("form").serialize(), function () {
        $this.dialog("close");
    });
},
```

Comment: I will update my question with the final solution. I only got it to work by declaring the variable outside the scope of the dialog itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of variable scope, as soon as you start the call back function for the `$.post` call, `this` is no longer the dialog box. Try calling `$("#modalAdd").dialog('close');` instead.

If you don't mind expanding your `$.post()` and `$.load()` calls, you can set the context of `this` to a certain element using the full `$.ajax()` method. [See the "context" option in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks and that makes complete sense with regards to the Save button however the context should be correct for the Cancel button yet that doesn't close the dialog either.

Comment: You're stating a new function on the cancel button, thus once again `this` is no longer the dialog. you could create a definitive var to the dialog object like in xdazz answer, if you're going to re-use it a lot.